# MySQL report - editor

Tags: mysql, sql, report, birt

I would like a tool that help creating an sql query (for non IT people) such as dbforge.

I would like our Non IT guys (such as operations) to create their own sql queries.

My second goal is to allow them to execute these queries on demand.

Our project is an enterprise project back office application (java \ spring \ my sql)

Are there any tools that do this?

P.S currently we're running birt, but the problem is that birt report creation requires a developer to create it due to the unfriendly interface

Answer (score 3):

This is not really an answer, just a comment, but it was getting too long to fit.

I think that if the database is at all complex, you are merely opening up a new batch of problems by doing this. Non-IT people do not understand the structure of the database, so you will have to create a simplified, pre-joined version of the database, or risk them running queries against objects they do not understand.

And if there is actually an IT group, to me that implies that the database is a little complex. You would probably be better off creating a bunch of canned reports, and letting them enter parameters to run said reports.

I know that this type of thing is requested all the time, but I have never seen it go well. One user will create a report that says you have 1000 widgets, or 500 open tickets, or whatever, and then another user will create a report that says 2000 widgets and 5 trillion tickets, and you will have to explain why both are wrong and why cartesian joins are problems. And that's assuming that they don't kill your system by writing ridiculous queries just out of curiosity. For example, I wonder how many of the customers from last year bought item A when it was on sale, but had never bought that item before?

Sorry to get on a soapbox. I fully expect downvotes, but I just want to warn you and perhaps give you a little anecdotal evidence, if there is still time to push back.

Comment: +1 There are times when the best answer to the question "How do I do this?" is "Don't!" - this includes a good explanation of why.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks. It scares me to see people write "I want non-IT people to be coding their own SQL." I have a hard enough time getting programmers to write valid SQL, much less proper SQL, so I would have zero expectations for non-IT people to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As MJB mentions creating canned reports with user entered parameters would be your best solution, as your question is written.

There is something of a conflict in your question as you want "Non IT guys to create their own sql queries" but at the same time you feel that "birt report creation requires a developer".  If they can write SQL, and learn JavaScript, they should be able to Build BIRT reports.

Assuming that you really want your Non IT guys to write SQL, and you don't want to purchase big dollar reporting solution.

Create [Data Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx) this allows you to create friendlier data sets for your Non IT guys, give them Read Only access to just the Data Views (Your IT people will need to create the login)

Have your Non_IT people Query the Dava Views with [SSMS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx) you probably already own this product and just need to start using it.

**Create the view**

```
• Open SQL Server 2008 R2 for the data base (i.e. winsvmnstst01)
• Drill down to the database (i.e. svmupmctst) 
• Right click "Views" , select "New View"
• On "Add Table" pop-up click "Close"
• Insert SQL (i.e.  select SCRELATIONM1.SOURCE, SCRELATIONM1.DEPEND  from dbo.SCRELATIONM1) 
• "Save" (top left) , lets you enter a name. click "Ok"
• Close window
```

**Add dataview to existing login** (actually  you add the login to the dataview)

```
• Right Click on View (i.e. DV_Global_ SCRELATIONM1), select "Properties"
• In Pop-up select "Permissions" (top left window)
• For "Users or roles" select "Search..." button
    ○ Click "Browse…"
    ○ Check login to add (i.e. itsmprocessowner)
    ○ Click "ok" & "0k"
• For "Permissions for  <value> (i.e. itsmprocessowner)
    ○ Check box at "Select" & "Grant"
        § If adding multiple login's this must be done for each
    ○ Click "ok"
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL Db try [Smart Report Maker](http://mysqlreports.com).  users can select the tables & columns they want to include in their reports , they also can visually define the grouping levels , sorting, Data Filters, Access rules and more
[image]